# Rate vs radius?

Tags: calculus

I have a question similar to this:

> The surface area of a snowball rolling down a hill is increasing at a rate of $12\pi\ cm^2/sec$. What is the radius of the snowball at the moment when the radius is increasing at $0.5\ cm/sec$?

But I have no idea how to solve it nor where to start. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Differentiate $A=4\pi r^2$ to get $\frac{dA}{dt}=8\pi r\frac{dr}{dt}$. Substitute the values of $\frac{dA}{dt}$ and $\frac{dr}{dt}$ to solve for $r$.

Comment: @Will, someone has been collecting rep like a busy beaver in the last few months. Kudos!